# range type mismatch vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a type mismatch error while comparing a range value to `""` or `vbNullString`. i read many similar q+a posts that deal with this issue.

*The data is all numbers or `""`.*

```
Sub vegetableCounting()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim ws1Range As Excel.range, ws2Range As Excel.range, ws3Range As Excel.range, ws2Loop As Excel.range
Dim ws1Row As Long, ws1Col As Long, ws2Row As Long, ws2Col As Long
'
Dim rowCounter As Long, colCounter As Long, rowsMendo As Long
Dim mendoSum As Double
'
Set ws1 = Sheets("shareSchedule")
Set ws2 = Sheets("shareDistribution")
Set ws3 = Sheets("vegCount")
'***not yet set to the full ranges***
Set ws1Range = ws1.range("E7:H11") 'shareSchedule
Set ws2Range = ws2.range("D7:BB17") 'shareDistribution
Set ws3Range = ws3.range("D7:BB11") 'vegetableCount
'***not yet set to the full ranges***
rowsMendo = 0
rowCounter = 0
colCounter = 0
mendoSum = 0

For ws1Row = 0 To ws1Range.Rows.count Step 1
    For ws1Col = 0 To ws1Range.Columns.count Step 1
        If ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value <> "" Then
            For Each ws2Loop In ws2Range '11rows*51cols = 561
                ws2Row = ws2Row + rowCounter + rowsMendo
                ws2Col = ws2Col + colCounter
                If ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, ws2Col).value = "" Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 24 And _
                    ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, ws2Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Then 'a MENDO match
                        If rowCounter < 3 Then
                            mendoSum = mendoSum + ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value * ws2Range.Offset(ws2Col, ws2Row)
                            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
                        ElseIf rowCounter = 3 Then
                            colCounter = colCounter + 1
                            rowCounter = 0
                        ElseIf colCounter = ws2Range.Columns.count + 1 And _
                        ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 24 And _
                        ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row + 4, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 24 Then
                            colCounter = 0
                            rowsMendo = rowsMendo + 3
                        ElseIf colCounter = ws2Range.Columns.count + 1 And _
                        ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And _
                        ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row + 4, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
                            colCounter = 0
                            rowsMendo = rowsMendo + 1
                        End If

                        ws3Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws2Col) = ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value * ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, ws2Col).value

                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next ws1Col
Next ws1Row

'for ws2
                'Offset(0, 0), Offset(1, 0), Offset(2, 0), then
                'Offset(0, 1), Offset(1, 1), Offset(2, 1), then
                'Offset(0, 2), Offset(1, 2), Offset(2, 2), then
                'etc
End Sub
```

i get the error on

```
  If ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value <> "" Then
```

and ill prob get it again on

```
If ws2Range.Offset(ws2Row, ws2Col).value = "" Then
```

any thoughts? here are some images of the worksheets im trying to pull from

Comment: You will get this error if `ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col)` contains an error - what is in this range?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `CStr` to convert the value to a String. `Format` could also be used as it handles `Null` whereas `CStr` would produce an error.

So either:

`If CStr(ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value) <> "" Then`

or

`If Format(ws1Range.Offset(ws1Row, ws1Col).value) <> "" Then`

Answer (score 0):

I don't usually use the Offset function, but you can access the cells in a specified range by directly specifiying the row and column like an array.

EG: ws2Range(ws2Row, ws2Col).value

You have to start in 1 for your iterations though, you'll get an error when you start at 0.

Comment: This doesn't address why the range object is returning an error when the value is being checked.

Comment: I don't think that's the right way to use the offset method, you may want to look at this http://www.ptraining.com/blog/2010/10/using-range-offset-in-excel-vba/. What I understood from the code user1799455 has provided is that, he/she wants to access a cell from a specified range. The example I gave allows me to access a cell from a specified range.

Answer (score 0):

when looking at the offset of a range, you get the entire range area, offset by your offset values.

e.g.

```
set a=sheets(1).range("A1:F40")
debug.print a.offset(1,1).address
```

giveas a result of

```
$B$2:$G$41
```

notice this is (A+1,1+1:F+1,40+1) and not a single cell

there are 2 options:

1. set your range to a single cell, and use offset to look at the area around that cell
2. use the range you have now, and use `cells(x,y)` to look in that range